# Get file from temporary Path

Tags: android, email, android-intent, filter, download

I am implementing one android app. In which i need to open any pdf (Either in Email attachment or saved sd card.) i need to show user to open that by my app.

Now i have set below code for set Intent Filer  :-

```
<activity android:name="x.x.x" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now I am getting path of File by below code: -

```
getIntent().getData().getEncodedPath();
```

It works fine when the file is in SD Card.

But when i try to open file in Email. Email have two options "View" and "Save".

If i use "View" without using "Save" i got the Temp. Path like "1/136/RAW"

I have seen other app acssing the file from this Temp. How can i access file from that Temp. Path.

Thanks for help.